# Economic effects of very large (>200%) household-debt-to-GDP-ratio in advanced economies

Tags: debt

[According to OECD figures](https://data.oecd.org/hha/household-debt.htm), five OECD countries have houshold-debt-to-GDP ratios in excess of 200%:

1. Denmark  292.0%
2. Netherlands  277.1%
3. Norway   221.8%
4. Australia    211.8%
5. Switzerland  211.2%

Most of this is in mortgages, so for the sake of the question, assume secured loans.

Is there any consensus on the macro-economic effects  of very high household-debt-to-GDP ratios?  I imagine such economies should be excessively sensitive to price changes in the housing market?

Comment: The problem is, every country has a different economic structure and financial policies.